# MVC 3 How to manually create the redirect URL?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm checking via `$.post` function if user is authenticated. If not, I want to redirect him to the login page and also put the current url in the `?RedirectUrl=` parameter (the same way like the `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()` does). Hot to do it ? Via Jquery or some .net method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom AuthorizeUser attribute and override HandleUnauthorizeUser(..).

Then you can verify is request is ajax request then return a jsonresult with proper value,which can be read by javascript in the view.

Try following code.( I have not tested yet)

```
public class CustomAuthorizeUserAttribute:AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var result = new JsonResult();
            result.Data = new
            {
                responseCode = 401,
                loginUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
            };
            filterContext.Result = result;
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

use it instead of [Authorize] attribute in controller actions.

Comment: +1 for elegant solution. However, perhaps 401 is a more appropriate response code.

Answer (score 1):

if he's not you could return a `RedirectResult`, if that doesn't work for you, I'd recommend producing the redirect url on the server side and passing it to jQuery via JSON